# Isosceles triangles with integer side lengths whose vertices are lattice points

Tags: geometry

I was wondering if such a triangle exists and I indeed found one: the triangle whose vertices are
$(0,0), (-33,56), (63,16)$. But is there a way to somehow "generate" these triangles? By the way, I'm only interested in isosceles triangles that don't have horizontal or vertical sides.

Here's what I've done so far: 
 To make things easier, I made the origin the vertex. The other vertices are denoted as $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$, and $$a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2=r^2$$$$(a-c)^2+(b-d)^2=n^2$$ where $a, b, c, d, r, $ and $n$ are integers. The second equation becomes $$a^2-2ac+c^2+b^2-2bd+d^2=2r^2-2ac-2bd$$$$2(r^2-(ac+bd))=n^2$$

I don't know how to proceed from this. Any ideas?

Comment: You can get some ideas ffom my [Rational triangles](http://grail.cba.csuohio.edu/~somos/rattri.html) page which links to my [Heronian triangle table](http://grail.cba.csuohio.edu/~somos/tritab.html) which has some formulas and coordinates for the vertices. Any triangle with integer area and sides can be placed so that its vertices are at integer lattice points.

Comment: @Somos ... though for example $5,5,6$ will have a vertical or horizontal side

Comment: But each lattice point is a  complex number. The triangle #2 with sides $5,5,6$ placed at $v=(4i,6+4i,3)$ can be expanded with $(48-20i)+(5+12i)v = (0,30+72i,63+16i)$. This has vertices $(0,0),(30,72),(63,16)$ with side lengths $65,65,78$.

Comment: $+1$ Sorry but what you just  tried is something called cosine rule $ac+bd$ is the dot product However It's curious for me how you wonder this question basically integer length is a problem

Comment: You took position vectors as equal sides of the isosceles triangle why don't you try another way possible let $p_1, p_2, c$ you took $p_1 = p_2≠c$ also try for $p_1 = c ≠ p_2$ where $p$ denotes position vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method. Given two Pythagorean triples: $\,a^2+b^2=c^2\,$
and $\,d^2+e^2=f^2,\,$ use the first one to create an isosceles triangle with
vertices $\,(-a,0),(a,0),(0,b)\,$ and sides $2a,c,c.\,$ Regard each vertex
as a point in the complex plane and multiply each point by $\,d+ei\,$ to
get the triangle with vertices $\,(-ad,-ae),(ad,ae),(-be,bd)\,$ and sides multiplied by $\,f.\,$ This triangle will have horizontal or vertical
sides iff $\,\,a/b=d/e\,$ or $\, a/b=e/d.\,$